# Como colocar un placeholder a un form_dropdown de codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, codeigniter-3

Los valores del dropdown son:

```
$gender = array
        (
            'name' => 'gender',
            'id' => 'gender',
            'class' =>  'select',
            'required' => 'required',


  'data-placeholder' => lang('spotmy.gender'), 

//aqui esta el mensaje que deberia mostrar como placeholder, pero sin embargo me muestra la primera de las opciones de abajo)


       'value' =>  set_select('gender')
            );

Estos son las únicas opciones que quiero en el dropdown:
        $options_gender = array
        (
            '1' => lang('spotmy.man'),
            '2' => lang('spotmy.woman')
        );

Así llamo en la vista al dropdown:
<?php echo form_dropdown($gender, $options_gender); ?>
```

[image: Quisiera que salga igual pero obviamente con las opciones sin quitar el placeholder]

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion solo era cuestion de agregar un campo vacio en las opciones y se pone el data-placeholder:

```
$options_gender = array
        (
            '' => '',
            '1' => lang('spotmy.man'),
            '2' => lang('spotmy.woman')
        );
```